# 3d Cistercian numbers mini game (MatPlotLib), inputting similar xyz coordinates 50 times, how to streamline?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Dear coding black belts,

My code is working but seems clunky.

- Take a random number from 1 to 99,999
- Display it in 3D in a modified version of the [Cistercian numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ciphers_of_the_Monks) from 13th century monks (adding one sagittal dimension)
- Ask for user input and check if the answer is correct.

I breakdown the random number to its digits components in a list:

```
Cistercian = randrange(1, 99999)
List_digits = [0, 0, 0] + [int(x) for x in str(Cistercian)]
units = List_digits[-1]
tens = List_digits[-2]
hundreds = List_digits[-3]
thousands = List_digits[-4]
man = List_digits[-5]
```

("man" means "10,000" in Japanese)

I predefined 14 points in the 3d space:

```
P1 = (-40, 0, 120)
P2 = (0, 0, 120)
P3 = (40, 0, 120)
P4 = (-40, 0, 80)
P5 = (0, 0, 80)
P6 = (40, 0, 80)
P7 = (-40, 0, 40)
P8 = (0, 0, 40)
P9 = (40, 0, 40)
P10 = (-40, 0, 0)
P11 = (0, 0, 0)
P12 = (40, 0, 0)
P13 = (0, -40, 80)
P14 = (0, -40, 40)
```

Then I map each digit as connections between the points above:

```
if thousands == 1:
    x_values1k = [P11[0], P10[0]]
    y_values1k = [P11[1], P10[1]]
    z_values1k = [P11[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values1k, y_values1k, z_values1k, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 2:
    x_values2k = [P8[0], P7[0]]
    y_values2k = [P8[1], P7[1]]
    z_values2k = [P8[2], P7[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values2k, y_values2k, z_values2k, color='k', lw=3)
```

It's used 50 times. I'd like to define a function that would only require the input of the coordinates once instead of re-writing the same 4 lines for each step. I'm struggling with how to manage that. I tried defining a function, but I was running into errors with the `plt.plot` aspect, where the x_values, z_values, y_values are different each of the 50 times.

for reference, lines 168 to 506, full code below
https://github.com/jelaludo/Cistercian3D/blob/main/main.py

Example of output:
[image: 3d Cistercian numbers with Matplotlib]

Here's the full code:

```
# Adding a sagittal dimension to the 13th Century Cistercian monks numerals
# to bring the upper limit from 9,999 to 99,999.

import numpy as np
# import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from random import randrange


# Cistercian = int(input("Please Input number from 1 to 99,999: "))
Cistercian = randrange(1, 99999)

# print(f"{Cistercian:,}")
List_digits = [0, 0, 0] + [int(x) for x in str(Cistercian)]
# Concatenating [0,0,0] for "padding"

units = List_digits[-1]
tens = List_digits[-2]
hundreds = List_digits[-3]
thousands = List_digits[-4]
man = List_digits[-5]

#"man" is 10,000 in Japanese

# print(man, " = Ten Thousands")
# print(thousands, " = Thousands")
# print(hundreds, " = Hundreds")
# print(tens, " = Tens")
# print(units, " = Units")

# Define the planes and that it is 3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# set initial Elevation and Azimuth view for the 3d graph
ax.view_init(15, -60)

# Set size for xyz space
ax.set_xlim3d(-150, 150)
ax.set_ylim3d(-150, 150)
ax.set_zlim3d(-150, 150)
# ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Structure of the matrix to represent Cistercian numbers, e.g. 11 to  2 is a straight line.
# 1  2  3
# 4  5  6
# 7  8  9
# 10 11  12
# + sagittal plane #13 at height #5 and #14 at height #8

P1 = (-40, 0, 120)
P2 = (0, 0, 120)
P3 = (40, 0, 120)
P4 = (-40, 0, 80)
P5 = (0, 0, 80)
P6 = (40, 0, 80)
P7 = (-40, 0, 40)
P8 = (0, 0, 40)
P9 = (40, 0, 40)
P10 = (-40, 0, 0)
P11 = (0, 0, 0)
P12 = (40, 0, 0)
P13 = (0, -40, 80)
P14 = (0, -40, 40)


# Center Points
def p11():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 0, color='k', lw=1)


def p8():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 40, color='k', lw=1)


def p5():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 80, color='k', lw=1)


def p2():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 120, color='k', lw=1)


p11()
p8()
p5()
p2()


# Sagittal Plane Points
def p13():
    ax.scatter(0, -40, 80, color='steelblue')


def p14():
    ax.scatter(0, -40, 40, color='steelblue')


p13()
p14()


# Thousands Points
def p7():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 40, color='slategrey', lw=1)


def p10():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 0, color='slategrey', lw=1)


p7()
p10()


# Hundreds Points
def p9():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 40, color='seagreen', lw=1)


def p12():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 0, color='seagreen', lw=1)


p9()
p12()


# Tens Points
def p1():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 120, color='darkgoldenrod', lw=1)


def p4():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 80, color='darkgoldenrod', lw=1)


p1()
p4()


# Units Points
def p3():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 120, color='darkcyan', lw=1)


def p6():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 80, color='darkcyan', lw=1)


p3()
p6()

p11()
p10()
# Draw center column
x_valuesCenter = [P11[0], P2[0]]
y_valuesCenter = [P11[1], P2[1]]
z_valuesCenter = [P11[2], P2[2]]
plt.plot(x_valuesCenter, y_valuesCenter, z_valuesCenter, color='k', lw=3)

userguess = Cistercian

# def ContinueTillFailure():
#     while userguess==Cistercian:

if man == 1:
    x_values1m = [P8[0], P14[0]]
    y_values1m = [P8[1], P14[1]]
    z_values1m = [P8[2], P14[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values1m, y_values1m, z_values1m, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 2:
    x_values2m = [P5[0], P13[0]]
    y_values2m = [P5[1], P13[1]]
    z_values2m = [P5[2], P13[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values2m, y_values2m, z_values2m, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 3:
    x_values3m = [P13[0], P8[0]]
    y_values3m = [P13[1], P8[1]]
    z_values3m = [P13[2], P8[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values3m, y_values3m, z_values3m, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 4:
    x_values4m = [P5[0], P14[0]]
    y_values4m = [P5[1], P14[1]]
    z_values4m = [P5[2], P14[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values4m, y_values4m, z_values4m, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 5:
    x_values5m = [P5[0], P14[0]]
    y_values5m = [P5[1], P14[1]]
    z_values5m = [P5[2], P14[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5m, y_values5m, z_values5m, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values5mb = [P14[0], P8[0]]
    y_values5mb = [P14[1], P8[1]]
    z_values5mb = [P14[2], P8[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5mb, y_values5mb, z_values5mb, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 6:
    x_values6m = [P13[0], P14[0]]
    y_values6m = [P13[1], P14[1]]
    z_values6m = [P13[2], P14[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values6m, y_values6m, z_values6m, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 7:
    x_values7m = [P13[0], P14[0]]
    y_values7m = [P13[1], P14[1]]
    z_values7m = [P13[2], P14[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7m, y_values7m, z_values7m, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values7mb = [P14[0], P8[0]]
    y_values7mb = [P14[1], P8[1]]
    z_values7mb = [P14[2], P8[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7mb, y_values7mb, z_values7mb, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 8:
    x_values8m = [P13[0], P14[0]]
    y_values8m = [P13[1], P14[1]]
    z_values8m = [P13[2], P14[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8m, y_values8m, z_values8m, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values8mb = [P5[0], P13[0]]
    y_values8mb = [P5[1], P13[1]]
    z_values8mb = [P5[2], P13[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8mb, y_values8mb, z_values8mb, color='k', lw=3)
elif man == 9:
    x_values9m = [P13[0], P14[0]]
    y_values9m = [P13[1], P14[1]]
    z_values9m = [P13[2], P14[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9m, y_values9m, z_values9m, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9mb = [P5[0], P13[0]]
    y_values9mb = [P5[1], P13[1]]
    z_values9mb = [P5[2], P13[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9mb, y_values9mb, z_values9mb, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9mc = [P14[0], P8[0]]
    y_values9mc = [P14[1], P8[1]]
    z_values9mc = [P14[2], P8[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9mc, y_values9mc, z_values9mc, color='k', lw=3)
else:
    p13()
# ## Draw corresponding Cistercian coordinates for thousands
if thousands == 1:
    x_values1k = [P11[0], P10[0]]
    y_values1k = [P11[1], P10[1]]
    z_values1k = [P11[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values1k, y_values1k, z_values1k, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 2:
    x_values2k = [P8[0], P7[0]]
    y_values2k = [P8[1], P7[1]]
    z_values2k = [P8[2], P7[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values2k, y_values2k, z_values2k, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 3:
    x_values3k = [P11[0], P7[0]]
    y_values3k = [P11[1], P7[1]]
    z_values3k = [P11[2], P7[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values3k, y_values3k, z_values3k, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 4:
    x_values4k = [P8[0], P10[0]]
    y_values4k = [P8[1], P10[1]]
    z_values4k = [P8[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values4k, y_values4k, z_values4k, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 5:
    x_values5k = [P8[0], P10[0]]
    y_values5k = [P8[1], P10[1]]
    z_values5k = [P8[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5k, y_values5k, z_values5k, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values5kb = [P11[0], P10[0]]
    y_values5kb = [P11[1], P10[1]]
    z_values5kb = [P11[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5kb, y_values5kb, z_values5kb, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 6:
    x_values6k = [P7[0], P10[0]]
    y_values6k = [P7[1], P10[1]]
    z_values6k = [P7[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values6k, y_values6k, z_values6k, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 7:
    x_values7k = [P7[0], P10[0]]
    y_values7k = [P7[1], P10[1]]
    z_values7k = [P7[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7k, y_values7k, z_values7k, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values7kb = [P11[0], P10[0]]
    y_values7kb = [P11[1], P10[1]]
    z_values7kb = [P11[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7kb, y_values7kb, z_values7kb, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 8:
    x_values8k = [P7[0], P10[0]]
    y_values8k = [P7[1], P10[1]]
    z_values8k = [P7[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8k, y_values8k, z_values8k, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values8kb = [P7[0], P8[0]]
    y_values8kb = [P7[1], P8[1]]
    z_values8kb = [P7[2], P8[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8kb, y_values8kb, z_values8kb, color='k', lw=3)
elif thousands == 9:
    x_values9k = [P7[0], P10[0]]
    y_values9k = [P7[1], P10[1]]
    z_values9k = [P7[2], P10[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9k, y_values9k, z_values9k, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9kb = [P7[0], P8[0]]
    y_values9kb = [P7[1], P8[1]]
    z_values9kb = [P7[2], P8[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9kb, y_values9kb, z_values9kb, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9kc = [P10[0], P11[0]]
    y_values9kc = [P10[1], P11[1]]
    z_values9kc = [P10[2], P11[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9kc, y_values9kc, z_values9kc, color='k', lw=3)
else:
    p10()

if hundreds == 1:
    x_values1c = [P11[0], P12[0]]
    y_values1c = [P11[1], P12[1]]
    z_values1c = [P11[2], P12[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values1c, y_values1c, z_values1c, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 2:
    x_values2c = [P8[0], P9[0]]
    y_values2c = [P8[1], P9[1]]
    z_values2c = [P8[2], P9[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values2c, y_values2c, z_values2c, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 3:
    x_values3c = [P11[0], P9[0]]
    y_values3c = [P11[1], P9[1]]
    z_values3c = [P11[2], P9[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values3c, y_values3c, z_values3c, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 4:
    x_values4c = [P8[0], P12[0]]
    y_values4c = [P8[1], P12[1]]
    z_values4c = [P8[2], P12[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values4c, y_values4c, z_values4c, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 5:
    x_values5c = [P8[0], P12[0]]
    y_values5c = [P8[1], P12[1]]
    z_values5c = [P8[2], P12[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5c, y_values5c, z_values5c, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values5cb = [P11[0], P12[0]]
    y_values5cb = [P11[1], P12[1]]
    z_values5cb = [P11[2], P12[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5cb, y_values5cb, z_values5cb, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 6:
    x_values6c = [P9[0], P12[0]]
    y_values6c = [P9[1], P12[1]]
    z_values6c = [P9[2], P12[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values6c, y_values6c, z_values6c, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 7:
    x_values7c = [P11[0], P12[0]]
    y_values7c = [P11[1], P12[1]]
    z_values7c = [P11[2], P12[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7c, y_values7c, z_values7c, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values7cb = [P12[0], P9[0]]
    y_values7cb = [P12[1], P9[1]]
    z_values7cb = [P12[2], P9[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7cb, y_values7cb, z_values7cb, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 8:
    x_values8c = [P12[0], P9[0]]
    y_values8c = [P12[1], P9[1]]
    z_values8c = [P12[2], P9[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8c, y_values8c, z_values8c, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values8cb = [P8[0], P9[0]]
    y_values8cb = [P8[1], P9[1]]
    z_values8cb = [P8[2], P9[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8cb, y_values8cb, z_values8cb, color='k', lw=3)
elif hundreds == 9:
    x_values9c = [P12[0], P9[0]]
    y_values9c = [P12[1], P9[1]]
    z_values9c = [P12[2], P9[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9c, y_values9c, z_values9c, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9cb = [P12[0], P11[0]]
    y_values9cb = [P12[1], P11[1]]
    z_values9cb = [P12[2], P11[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9cb, y_values9cb, z_values9cb, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9cc = [P9[0], P8[0]]
    y_values9cc = [P9[1], P8[1]]
    z_values9cc = [P9[2], P8[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9cc, y_values9cc, z_values9cc, color='k', lw=3)
else:
    p12()

if tens == 1:
    x_values1t = [P1[0], P2[0]]
    y_values1t = [P1[1], P2[1]]
    z_values1t = [P1[2], P2[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values1t, y_values1t, z_values1t, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 2:
    x_values2t = [P5[0], P4[0]]
    y_values2t = [P5[1], P4[1]]
    z_values2t = [P5[2], P4[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values2t, y_values2t, z_values2t, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 3:
    x_values3t = [P2[0], P4[0]]
    y_values3t = [P2[1], P4[1]]
    z_values3t = [P2[2], P4[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values3t, y_values3t, z_values3t, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 4:
    x_values4t = [P1[0], P5[0]]
    y_values4t = [P1[1], P5[1]]
    z_values4t = [P1[2], P5[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values4t, y_values4t, z_values4t, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 5:
    x_values5t = [P1[0], P2[0]]
    y_values5t = [P1[1], P2[1]]
    z_values5t = [P1[2], P2[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5t, y_values5t, z_values5t, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values5tb = [P1[0], P5[0]]
    y_values5tb = [P1[1], P5[1]]
    z_values5tb = [P1[2], P5[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5tb, y_values5tb, z_values5tb, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 6:
    x_values6t = [P1[0], P4[0]]
    y_values6t = [P1[1], P4[1]]
    z_values6t = [P1[2], P4[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values6t, y_values6t, z_values6t, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 7:
    x_values7t = [P1[0], P2[0]]
    y_values7t = [P1[1], P2[1]]
    z_values7t = [P1[2], P2[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7t, y_values7t, z_values7t, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values7tb = [P1[0], P4[0]]
    y_values7tb = [P1[1], P4[1]]
    z_values7tb = [P1[2], P4[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7tb, y_values7tb, z_values7tb, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 8:
    x_values8t = [P4[0], P1[0]]
    y_values8t = [P4[1], P1[1]]
    z_values8t = [P4[2], P1[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8t, y_values8t, z_values8t, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values8tb = [P5[0], P4[0]]
    y_values8tb = [P5[1], P4[1]]
    z_values8tb = [P5[2], P4[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8tb, y_values8tb, z_values8tb, color='k', lw=3)
elif tens == 9:
    x_values9t = [P4[0], P1[0]]
    y_values9t = [P4[1], P1[1]]
    z_values9t = [P4[2], P1[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9t, y_values9t, z_values9t, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9tb = [P5[0], P4[0]]
    y_values9tb = [P5[1], P4[1]]
    z_values9tb = [P5[2], P4[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9tb, y_values9tb, z_values9tb, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9tc = [P1[0], P2[0]]
    y_values9tc = [P1[1], P2[1]]
    z_values9tc = [P1[2], P2[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9tc, y_values9tc, z_values9tc, color='k', lw=3)
else:
    p1()

if units == 1:
    x_values1u = [P3[0], P2[0]]
    y_values1u = [P3[1], P2[1]]
    z_values1u = [P3[2], P2[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values1u, y_values1u, z_values1u, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 2:
    x_values2u = [P5[0], P6[0]]
    y_values2u = [P5[1], P6[1]]
    z_values2u = [P5[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values2u, y_values2u, z_values2u, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 3:
    x_values3u = [P2[0], P6[0]]
    y_values3u = [P2[1], P6[1]]
    z_values3u = [P2[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values3u, y_values3u, z_values3u, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 4:
    x_values4u = [P3[0], P5[0]]
    y_values4u = [P3[1], P5[1]]
    z_values4u = [P3[2], P5[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values4u, y_values4u, z_values4u, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 5:
    x_values5u = [P3[0], P2[0]]
    y_values5u = [P3[1], P2[1]]
    z_values5u = [P3[2], P2[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5u, y_values5u, z_values5u, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values5ub = [P3[0], P5[0]]
    y_values5ub = [P3[1], P5[1]]
    z_values5ub = [P3[2], P5[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values5ub, y_values5ub, z_values5ub, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 6:
    x_values6u = [P3[0], P6[0]]
    y_values6u = [P3[1], P6[1]]
    z_values6u = [P3[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values6u, y_values6u, z_values6u, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 7:
    x_values7u = [P2[0], P3[0]]
    y_values7u = [P2[1], P3[1]]
    z_values7u = [P2[2], P3[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7u, y_values7u, z_values7u, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values7ub = [P3[0], P6[0]]
    y_values7ub = [P3[1], P6[1]]
    z_values7ub = [P3[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values7ub, y_values7ub, z_values7ub, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 8:
    x_values8u = [P3[0], P6[0]]
    y_values8u = [P3[1], P6[1]]
    z_values8u = [P3[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8u, y_values8u, z_values8u, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values8ub = [P5[0], P6[0]]
    y_values8ub = [P5[1], P6[1]]
    z_values8ub = [P5[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values8ub, y_values8ub, z_values8ub, color='k', lw=3)
elif units == 9:
    x_values9u = [P3[0], P6[0]]
    y_values9u = [P3[1], P6[1]]
    z_values9u = [P3[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9u, y_values9u, z_values9u, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9ub = [P5[0], P6[0]]
    y_values9ub = [P5[1], P6[1]]
    z_values9ub = [P5[2], P6[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9ub, y_values9ub, z_values9ub, color='k', lw=3)
    x_values9uc = [P3[0], P2[0]]
    y_values9uc = [P3[1], P2[1]]
    z_values9uc = [P3[2], P2[2]]
    plt.plot(x_values9uc, y_values9uc, z_values9uc, color='k', lw=3)
else:
    plt.show()


# Center Points
def p11():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 0, color='k', lw=1)


def p8():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 40, color='k', lw=1)


def p5():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 80, color='k', lw=1)


def p2():
    ax.scatter(0, 0, 120, color='k', lw=1)


p11()
p8()
p5()
p2()


# Sagittal Plane Points
def p13():
    ax.scatter(0, -40, 80, color='steelblue')


def p14():
    ax.scatter(0, -40, 40, color='steelblue')


p13()
p14()


# Thousands Points
def p7():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 40, color='slategrey', lw=1)


def p10():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 0, color='slategrey', lw=1)


p7()
p10()


# Hundreds Points
def p9():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 40, color='seagreen', lw=1)


def p12():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 0, color='seagreen', lw=1)


p9()
p12()


# Tens Points
def p1():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 120, color='darkgoldenrod', lw=1)


def p4():
    ax.scatter(-40, 0, 80, color='darkgoldenrod', lw=1)


p1()
p4()

# Units Points


def p3():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 120, color='darkcyan', lw=1)


def p6():
    ax.scatter(40, 0, 80, color='darkcyan', lw=1)


p3()
p6()

# define two points, create lists of xyz values, and plot a line between them

# ax.set_xlabel("X-Axis")
# ax.set_ylabel("Y-Axis")
# ax.set_zlabel("Z-Axis")

# from pylab import rcParams
# rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 20

#hide axis values by setting them to blank []
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_title("3D Cistercian Numerals (Sagittal for 10k)")




plt.show()
plt.savefig('/Users/gfabr/Pictures/HalfFailedIfBlank%s.png')

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

ROOT = tk.Tk()
ROOT.withdraw()
# the input dialog
prompt = simpledialog.askstring(title="Test",
                                  prompt="What's your best guess?:")

# https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html

# userguess = int(input("Best guess ? :"))
userguess = int(prompt)

print(f"{userguess:,}")
print(f"{Cistercian:,}")

from termcolor import colored
if userguess==Cistercian:
    print(colored("correct", 'green'))
else:
    print(colored("not quite", 'red'))

# to do
# simplify recurring code
# option to re-show previous number
# save graph to a png file
# dynamically name the save file .png to include the number created (with %s ?)
# increment, track how many you got right in a row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid repeating yourself

There is *a lot* of code duplication in your program. This means you had to type in more than necessary, and the chance of bugs getting in your code has increased as well. Whenever you find you have lots of similar sections of code, find a way to reduce that.

For example, when you define `P1`, `P2` and so on, it would be easy to make a typo and define the same variable twice for example. In any case, this looks like a job for a list:

```
P = [(-40, 0, 120),
     (0, 0,  120),
     ...
     (0, -40, 40)]
```

But even then it's easy to make mistakes when entering all those coordinates themselves. And how were they created in the first place? You could just write code to *generate* those numbers:

```
P = []

# Add Cistercian numbers
for z in 120, 80, 40, 0:
    for x in -40, 0, 40:
        P.append((x, 0, z))

# Add sagittal planes
P.append((0, -40, 80))
P.append((0, -40, 40))
```

Note, the array `P` above starts counting at zero, so `P[0]` is equivalent to your `P1`.

Then there are the functions `p1()` to `p14()`. You define them and use them only once, which is a bit silly. But worse, they repeat the coordinates defined in `P`. Consider writing a function that draws a series of points or lines:

```
def draw(points, indices, color, lw=0):
    for i in indices:
        p = points[i]
        ax.scatter(p[0], p[1], p[2], color=color, lw=lw)
```

And then use it like so:

```
draw(P, [10, 7, 4, 1], 'k', 1) # Center points
draw(P, [12, 13], 'steelblue') # Sagittal plane points
...
```

Now try to apply these techniques to the huge `if`-`else` chains you have.

## Avoid hardcoded numbers

[Hardcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) numbers can be a problem. Consider for example that all your coordinates are multiples of 40. I guess that's because it turns out to be a nice scale when you create the plot on your screen. But what if you want to change the scale later? Now you have to replace all instances of `-40`, `40`, `80` and so on, and hope you don't accidentily replace a `40` that had a completely different meaning. Avoid hardcoding numbers, instead create variables as soon as possible for things and use those from then on. For example:

```
# Set size for xyz space
size = 150
ax.set_xlim3d(-size, size)
ax.set_ylim3d(-size, size)
ax.set_zlim3d(-size, size)
```